# SQL Column Contains ID of Another Row

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, subquery

Suppose I have a SQL database `my_table` of the following form where one column contains the id of another row. How can I select both the name column of the given row and the name of the underlying id row?

[image: my_table]

For example, selecting ids 1 and 2 via `SELECT name, ?  FROM my_table WHERE id IN (1, 2)` should return:

```
name, underlying_name
Apple,, 
Pear, Strawberry
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self-join, I presume:

```
select a.id, a.name, b.name
from my_table a left join my_table b on b.id = a.underlying_id
order by a.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Or a correlated subquery for the simple case:

```sql
SELECT name
    , (SELECT name FROM my_table WHERE id = a.underlying_id) AS underlying_name
FROM   my_table a
ORDER  BY id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would think you'd want to get rid of the third row since you have that data point in a separate column. A `where` condition can be added to handle that

```
select a.id, a.name, b.name as underlying_name
from t a 
left join t b on b.id = a.underlying_id
where a.id not in (select underlying_id 
                   from t
                   where underlying_id is not null);
```